# Sending Facebook message

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook

Just trying to send a Facebook message with python.

Code:

```
import fbchat

from fbchat import Client

from fbchat.models import *

client = Client("my_username", "my_password")

#help(fb.Client.send)

#client.send(text="This is a test", thread_id="christopher.batey", thread_type=ThreadType.USER)

name = "christopher.batey"

friends = client.searchForUsers(name)

friend = friends[0]

uid = friend.uid

msg = "This is a test"

print(help(client.send))

client.send(Message(text=msg, thread_id="christopher.batey", thread_type=ThreadType.USER))
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "main.py", line 13, in
>
> ```
> client.send(Message(text=msg, thread_id="christopher.batey", thread_type=ThreadType.USER))
> ```
>
> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'thread_id'

Comment: Facebooks Terms of Service say that you need to use the API to interact with them. The fbchat library is not using the API.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the API but from the documentation, it looks like the proper call would be:

```
client.send(Message(text=msg), thread_id="christopher.batey", thread_type=ThreadType.USER)
```

where the message object is the first argument passed into send, followed by thread_id and thread_type.

Comment: With this edit this occurs...      Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>

    client.send(Message(text=msg), thread_id="uid", thread_type=ThreadType.USER)

  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fbchat/_client.py", line 1107, in send

    return self._doSendRequest(data)

  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fbchat/_client.py", line 1066, in _doSendRequest

    j = self._post("/messaging/send/", data)

  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/s

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time exploring this module a few years ago.

Quickly looking back at the github examples the the thread_id should be a number.

As such change

```py
client.send(Message(text=msg, thread_id="christopher.batey", thread_type=ThreadType.USER))
```

to

```py
client.send(Message(text=msg), thread_id=uid, thread_type=ThreadType.USER)
```

in your code. As your uid is that of the friend you want to send too.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>

    client.send(Message(text=msg), thread_id="uid", thread_type=ThreadType.USER)

  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fbchat/_client.py", line 1107, in send

    return self._doSendRequest(data)

  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fbchat/_client.py", line 1066, in _doSendRequest

    j = self._post("/messaging/send/", data)

  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fbchat/_client.py", li

Comment: I think this may have to do with your friend = friends[0], the search doe not necessarily put the best match first. Have you tried printing out friends and seeing what the first element is. In the past I always found the uid's I need manually or by getting the thread id when something was sent to me.

Comment: @ChristopherBatey one way to check this is to change the thread_id to client.uid rather than just uid and see if the message sends to yourself - if that works then it is an issue with the uid's you are finding.